# IDE for realtime collaboration that works with C/C++, C#, .Net

Tags: c++, c, collaboration

I'm looking for an IDE that I can collaborate with other people.  I'd like to have real-time editing and color coordination (meaning if Bob is online and changes some code it will high lite his changes, similar to sharing a Document on Google).

I've tried searching via Google but I can't find anything that actually suits my needs.  I'm currently a college student and have projects to do with other class mates, but using Pastebin is a bit cumbersome as I have to have an IDE open + a web browser, then copy paste, share etc.

Is there any IDE out there that will compile for C/C++, C#, .Net etc with real-time collaboration?  If I have to set up a server on my desktop to make it work I have no problems doing so

Comment: The homework tag is [deprecated](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147100/the-homework-tag-is-now-officially-deprecated).

Comment: you have just found a niche market, now go and make some money.

Comment: I don't think it is a market for simultaneous co-programming in C.

Comment: If you've got multiple people editing the same file, you're doing it wrong.  Break up your classes into multiple files, and assign each one to a different person.  Define interfaces early and avoid WTFs at all costs.

Answer (score 7):

I believe that in practical terms, using a distributed versioning system (like [git](http://git-scm.com/), perhaps thru [gitorious](http://gitorious.org/) or [github](http://github.com)) is a wiser idea, at least for usual programming languages like C (and you need a social convention, at least like Bob is working on file `foo.c` or on function `foofoo` while Alice focuses on `bar.c` or on function `barbar`). You may want to communicate in real time using IRC, chat, pastebin, etc .... in addition of git. You probably won't edit the same line (or perhaps even the same function) two distant people at a time.

The semantics of programming language like C is not fit to the idea of a simultanous edition of a single source at the very same time. (Defining languages friendly to this co-development idea is still a research topic).

BTW, you don't need an IDE to code in C or C++ (especially on Linux, which gives you a lot of other tools `emacs` or perhaps `vim` or `gedit` or `geany`, `grep`, `make`, `ctags`, `git`, `awk`, ... to use together). A big lot of very large C or C++ free software programs (GCC, the Linux kernel, Gnome/GTK, Qt/KDE, LibreOffice ....) are coded by many qualified people without IDEs. This is IMHO quite significant.

Comment: I second git + IRC. Getting acquinted with rock solid technology is a big win for students.

Comment: This I know, I just don't feel like installing Linux atm.  I was planning on re-installing Mint (don't ask why I don't have it anymore), on the weekend.

Comment: If you think of it as distributed pair programming then it's a little more reasonable.  You wouldn't want to use it instead of a VCS like git, but it might be a nice supplement to have for working on the bits that make sense to do pair programming for.

Comment: I edited my answer to mention `vim` or `gedit` or `geany`

Answer (score 5):

I suggest to try:

- http://moonedit.com/ - simple real-time editor
- http://www.saros-project.org/DemoVideo - real-time editor for Eclipse (so you could use C++ there)

at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collaborative_real-time_editor there are plenty suggestions.

Comment: Saros project looks really promising!

Comment: ***Warning:*** Firefox now reports moonedit as a malware site (assuming it hasn't before).

Answer (score 2):

This is an old thread but in case others are still interested in this topic/capability there are a bunch of web based IDEs nowadays.  If you Google "web ide", you'll get a decent list of collaborative web IDEs.  For completeness, I'll list one that I've used and liked:

[Cloud9 IDE](http://www.c9.io)

Aside from small homework assignments, you are better off using a version control system like [GIT](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-About-Version-Control) or [Hg](http://mercurial.selenic.com/).  Though they are overkill for most small homework assignments; especially if it's an intro class and most students are already having a hard enough time learning the programming material by itself.

One other note is that a web based IDE is not necessarily mutually exclusive to using VCS.  You can use GIT inside of Cloud9 IDE.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at EFC, http://www.eclipse.org/ecf/.
More specifically Cola, http://vimeo.com/1195398.

Comment: A "build your own" approach looks like a big task for someone who is learning to program in college...

Comment: I'm looking at Eclipse right now, I just tried to open my class.c file and its blank inside of the IDE...

Comment: This doesn't really help me since i have no idea how to set it up, I've spent the last 2-3 hours trying to figure it out

Comment: I've set it up once in the past; As far as I can remember it was a one click install from software updates. However I'd like to add that version control is a better way to go about it.

Answer (score 1):

Save yourself the trouble and use version control of some sort. Be it git, hg, svn, or what have you. Pick your poison, but this is a large part of what version control exists for. For communication? AIM, IRC, Skype, it doesn't really matter.

In this case, you can either have good version control, a good IDE, and a good Chat program or you can have one program that syncs your code, allows you to chat, and allows you to edit code, but does all of the above poorly.

Answer (score 1):

Check out Squad:

http://squadedit.com/

Hosted service so setup is easy, and it supports C++ syntax highlighting.